# How can I change my xampp username not as 'root'

Tags: xampp, localhost

I want to change my xampp username to a defined username. Can anyone tel me where can I change my username? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Change your username and password at `localhost/phpmyadmin` then go to `xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`. Look for the lines below, without the quoted material.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'UserName';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NewPassword';
```