# how to change (root) username in phpmyAdmin with xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Hello Am using " vps server" for my website (Using Xampp on vps)

And I need to share (phpMyAdmin) with world to enter it easily from any computer, and
I did it without problems

But for security I want to Change "root" to another username so no one can enter with root

Note: I want to remove "root" completely from accounts and create another account with a different username or edit root not only to add a new account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change my xampp username not as 'root'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221609/how-can-i-change-my-xampp-username-not-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

```
> click on server name eg.127.0.0.1
>> delete root then / add another user if you want
>>> inside code replace all root's with newUser
>>>> please read whatever action you are executing / make backup first
```

[image: that most upper round is my server name / link]